# django reverse foreignkey is empty

Tags: django, django-models

All,

I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=False,null=False)
    parent_model = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True,related_name="child_models")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

    def add_child(self,child):
        child.parent_model = self
```

python manage.py shell:

```
>>> foo = MyModel(name='foo')
>>> bar = MyModel(name='bar')
>>> foo.add_child(bar)
>>> bar.parent_model
<MyModel: foo>
>>> foo.child_models.all()
[]
```

Why is the reverse foreign key "child_models" empty when the foreign key "parent_model" has been set?

Thanks

---

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from questionnaire.models import *
>>> foo = TestModel(name='foo')
>>> bar = TestModel(name='bar')
>>> foo.save()
>>> bar.save()
>>> foo.add_child(bar)
>>> bar.get_parent()
<TestModel: foo>
>>> foo.get_children()
[]
```

---

```
def myView(request):
  foo = MyModel(name='foo')
  bar = MyModel(name='bar')
  foo.add_child(bar)

  # I don't want to have to save foo or bar before I know that the data is correct,
  # or that the user has even pressed submit

  if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      # somewhere in here is where I want to do the saving to the db
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.save()
      form.save_m2m()
    else:
      form = MyForm(instance=foo)

  return render_to_response('my_template.html', {"form":form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Do you save the child after setting the parent model?

Comment: @Wogan - Yes, I have tried saving both foo and bar both before and after these operations.  It made no difference.

Comment: Please then post the session where you create the models, save them, then add the child and save it again, then access the reverse relation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - see the edit to my original question.

Comment: But you haven't saved bar after adding it as a child to foo.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - You are right.  Once I save bar, the parent/child relationship exists.  Is there a way around this?  Consider the case where I want to present a hierachy in a form; In the view I, I'll only want to save things in the POST and not in the GET.  See my next edit.

Answer (score 2):

Ther eare two possible reasons:

**In your `add_child` method:**

*That is not your problem, but you can come accross this too*

```
def add_child(self,child):
    child.parent_model = self
```

you do not save `child`. So your changes do not reflected to database. But since your `querysets` are also objects:

```
>>> foo.add_child(bar)
>>> bar.parent_model
<MyModel: foo>
```

`bar` object keeps its new data, but since you did not save it to your database, this do not reflects to `foo`

**You are dealing with *out-of-date* data:**

*This is your problem*

```
>>> foo = TestModel(name='foo')
>>> bar = TestModel(name='bar')
>>> foo.save()
>>> bar.save()
```

You save them and both `foo` and `bar` object carry the same values as their relevnt database records.

```
 >>> foo.add_child(bar)
```

You update `bar` **object**, but do not save it. So each database data are not updated, only `bar` object is changed.

```
>>> bar.get_parent()
<TestModel: foo>
>>> foo.get_children()
[]
```

Your `bar` object is updated. Since you do not save the changes to your database and refresh related objects (retreive them from the database again) then yould not be updated. So your `foo` object still *out-of-date*

You must save the data and retreive required objects from the database again...

```
>>> foo = TestModel(name='foo')
>>> bar = TestModel(name='bar')
>>> foo.save()
>>> bar.save()  # Instead of make a second save, you can discard this save step and save after `add_child` 
>>> foo.add_child(bar)
>>> bar.save()
>>> foo = MyModel.objects.get(name="foo")
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Your explanation makes sense and I understand why the objects weren't being updated.  If you look at my recent edit to my question you can see that I am still interested in representing this information without resorting to saving models.